# Gradle - throwing errors during plugin apply - "Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate()"

Tags: error-handling, gradle

I wish to throw an error during the plugin apply method, in order to inform the user of missing settings (and help them fix it). I'm seeing the following error repeatedly:

`Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.`

I'm looking to do two things:

1. Notify afterEvaluate() in a proper manner
2. Avoid producing the huge stack trace - only the exception message is needed

The last comment in [Gradle bug 1617](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2617) says the following:

*> What happens is that the afterEvaluate closure is executed even though apply() threw an exception.

This is not surprising. The closure you give to afterEvaluate() is a callback, and fires even if evaluation failed.
You should check the project's state (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getState()) in your afterEvaluate callback and return if it's in a failed state.*

After a number of tests, I have not been able to figure out the proper way to structure the call to getState().

Summary of gradle plugin file:

```
class j2objc implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {

        project.afterEvaluate {
            // Setup basic paths
            def j2objcHome = System.getenv()['J2OBJC_HOME']
            if (j2objcHome == null) {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException(
                        'j2objc home not set, <helpful instructions to fix>')
            }

            project.tasks.create(name: 'j2objcTranslate', type: Exec) {
                // Should not be called if there's a failure
                description 'Translates all the java source files in to Objective-C using j2objc'
                // <implementation>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full Error including part of the long stack trace that I'd like to hide:

```
$ gradlew base:j2objcTranslate
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: j2objc home not set, this can be set using J2OBJC_HOME environment variable or within build.gradle by adding: j2objcConfig { j2objcHome = <path> }, e.g. j2objcConfig { j2objcHome = "$projectDir/../j2objc/"}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
<a huge number more lines>
```

### Update

There was an error in the parent gradle file. When this was fixed it produced far better output (copied below). Even so, it would be nice to produce a better error message when there are multiple failures as it was described before.

```
$ gradlew base:j2objcTranslate

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/brunobowden/dev/myproject/base/j2objc.gradle' line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':base'.
    > j2objc home not set, <helpful message>
```

Comment: What should be ignored?

Comment: The plugin shouldn't be doing all of its work in `afterEvaluate`. The env check can be done immediately, and also the task should be added immediately. Perhaps the env check should be done only when the task executes, or only if the task is scheduled to be executed. Otherwise, even something like `gradle tasks` will fail with "j2objc home not set". There should also be a check for a project property "j2objc" (an extension would be even better) or the like, as that's easier to set (e.g. in `init.gradle`) than an env variable.

Comment: Opal - the comment was unintentional. I couldn't see the remove comment button, so I phrased it to be ignored.

Comment: Peter, thanks for your input. I agree on your comments, the code it structured this was as it's a redacted version of what I posted on the forum: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/j2objc-plugin-java-to-objective-c-transpiler-feedback-requested Let me do another StackOverflow which I think gets closer to my real issue about accessing extension objects.

Comment: A good example of doing this properly is in the plugin that I developed on the basis of a lot of useful feedback from the folks at Gradleware: https://gist.github.com/brunobowden/58d6e311ab96760fc371

Answer (score 0):

I my case, after adding ANDROID_PATH, it worked.